# Error "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'" in Add-Migration command for first time (EntityFramework Core)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, backend, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying create my first entityFramework app for a website and I can't even create the database.
The project compiles withtout problems and everything looks fine, but when I call the "Add-migration someName" I receive this error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the
> different patterns supported at design time, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

This is my ApplicationContext:

```
using Backend_SMOL.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Backend_SMOL
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)            
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The Startup.cs:
This one was not created by default with the project as I see in other videos. Maybe the problem is here.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Backend_SMOL
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                //options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));
                options.UseSqlServer("Server=FurkiPc;Database=SMOL_ERP;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
                );

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more info, please ask me and I will provide as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance!

I tried everything... Moving the connection string to plain text, changing names, creating new project... I dont have more ideas

Comment: Can you please show `appsettings.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation and the code fragment, it solved the error. Now I have other error but I will check it tomorrow.

> *No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring'
> method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider.
> If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.*

Thanks!

Comment: For this you can post new question, and share the newly posted question link here; so that I can check. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).